# How to decode an email attachment received as a Base64 text

Tags: email, base64, attachment, decoding

I have an email backup file which is purely text. How can I retrieve the document (PDF, images, word files) attached to it as a normal file?

Comment: If you are on Linux, the [base64](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) program does a splendid job of converting the Base64 string (e.g., `JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW`) to your target format. You can find some examples [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178521/how-can-i-decode-a-base64-string-from-the-command-line).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Select the long string of text which appears in your email. That is probably one of the attachments, it usually starts like this:

   ```
   --bcaec554d754b0f76a04d9fda578--
   --bcaec554d754b0f77204d9fda57a
   Content-Type: application/pdf; name="test.pdf"
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Otest.pdf"
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
   X-Attachment-Id: 9ba6310dffca527f_0.1
   ```
2. Copy this long string and paste it in the Base64 decoder [found here](https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html).
3. Download the output and rename it by adding the appropriate extension to it. For example `testfile.pdf` or `filename.docx`.

There you go. You just recreated your lost attachment using Base64 decoding.

Comment: What if I want to do the decoding on my own in a programatical way?

Comment: @OzanKurt Can you please give a bit of more context as to which programming language you intend to use, and will you be running this locally or on a specific server. Also is fetching email attachments involved etc?

Comment: I already managed to make it work via PHP. It somehow didn't work when I did the process manually though... Kind of weird.

Comment: @OzanKurt Perfect! Glad you got sorted. Maybe best if you could summarise your answer here below for anyone else who might be interested. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in PHP decode to a file

```
 function base64_to_jpeg( $inputfile, $outputfile ) { 
  /* read data (binary) */ 
  $ifp = fopen( $inputfile, "rb" ); 
  $imageData = fread( $ifp, filesize( $inputfile ) ); 
  fclose( $ifp ); 
  /* encode & write data (binary) */ 
  $ifp = fopen( $outputfile, "wb" ); 
  fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $imageData ) ); 
  fclose( $ifp ); 
  /* return output filename */ 
  return( $outputfile ); 
}
```

in HTML if you want to just display in web / using HTML

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,Your_Base_64_Code_Here">
```

You can use For use as CSS background:

```
url('data:image/png;base64,Your_Base_64_Code_Here')
```